# Spring: How to customize UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security with XML configuration.

I want to customize the method `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication()`.

What would be the easiest way ?

If I add a custom filter with the same position as `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, I feel I have to rewrite or wire a bunch of stuff (what happens to my configuration of `<sec:form-login/>` ?). But if that's the best option, then what should I wire to have the same `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` configuration as before?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you need to customize? Generally there are better ways/other components you can modify/extend/add.

Comment: I want to check that a string I inserted (previously) in the user session matches what the user has put in the login form (basically, I want to check that the user has answered a correct captcha)

Comment: Why modify the filter for that, just add an additional filter before the username one to have that checked. No need to modify classes, just add an additional one.

Comment: Something like    `<sec:custom-filter ref="MyFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/> `  ? I think I tried it before, and if I recall correctly the `doFilter()` was also called on the GET login page, instead of just the POST form. Moreover, I need to retrieve the user field from the form. It is configured for the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, through the username-parameter of `<sec:form-login/> ` . Thus, should I duplicate this attribute value in my own filter ? It feels weird that I can't configure in a single place.

Comment: In the filter program what to execute when (depending on which filter you extend this might be overriding a method or a simple if statement). You want to check a captcha string, what has that to do with the username? Why would you need that. This being said if you configure your own modified usernamepasswordfileter you can no longer use `<sec:form-login />` as that will configure the default filter.

Comment: Not all users have to enter the captcha, only those that have multiple failure attempts. I thus need to check a service that gives that number of attempts for a given login. Hence the need for the login field. Do you confirm that `<sec:custom-filter ref="MyFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/> ` should then be the way to go, and that `MyFilter` will only be called when a POST to /login is made ?

Comment: The execution of the POST should be embedded in the filter. The form login also has this embedded in the filter itself.

Comment: @gus.jz See https://leaks.wanari.com/2017/11/28/how-to-make-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-with-spring-security

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure what you mean by 'should be embedded'. Am I supposed to do something manually ?

Comment: Check the type of request if you need to invoke further logic or not.

Comment: So just to sum up what I understand so far: I need to add a custom filter before `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER`. This filter is called by default for each server request. However I only need it for authentication attempts (ie, `POST`s to `/login` in my case). But how can I "copy" this logic from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter ? It feels wrong if I have to suppose that the login path is /login, when it can be changed in the `<sec:form-login/>`... Is there another way to retrieve that logic ?

Comment: @M.Deinum And also, how do I set my Filter to call the FailureHandler that is set in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter ? As I said in my original question, I have a feeling that I have to re-wire a bunch of stuff, and it would appear that creating a new filter doesn't solve all these issues...

Comment: Why would you need to call the `FailureHandler`? Just throw an exception which extends `AuthenticationException` and it will be converted by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. But as stated, you can still extend the Spring Security filter, but you have to manually configure it, there is no more use of `<sec:form-login />` then.

Comment: Throw an exception where? If I throw an exception in doFilterInternal() of MyFilter which extends OncePerRequestFilter, it results in a 500 error, the exception is not caught anywhere, and in any case is not redirected to the FailureHandler of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. As a reminder, my goal is just to slightly customize the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter by adding an extra check, but otherwise keeping the initial logic. So on authentication failure, the failure must be treated as with the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: ... And I noticed yet another thing I seem to have to copy from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, should I add a new filter: the notifications of failure/success events (in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication())... Am I really on the right track to "simply" customize the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?!